# how to change dom of one frame bye the event of another frame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, jsp-tags

i have one page and i have written code

i am using jquery. now i want to append some html elements in some div of FormView.jsp, in response to some of the event fired in showFormPage.jsp.

how can i do it?
help me..

Comment: Include code in your questions - that way, it's much easier to give answers

Answer (score 1):

In your event handler you can target a element ID of say `section` in another frame called say `other_frame`, like so:

```
$("#button").click(function() { 
  $("#section", top.frames["other_frame"].document).append("<b>your html elements</b>");
});
```

Comment: other_frame is the id of other frame or name?

Comment: @MohdAdnan: `other_frame` refers to the frame name.